# Prevent _id field from being supplied in a MongoDB query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I'm using Mongoose in NodeJS to control a MongoDB database.

I'm creating an API and for obvious security reasons, I want to prevent the auto generated document `_id` field from getting replaced by a manually generated one in the API request.

Schema:

```
{ name: String }
```

Creating a document:

```
const record = {
    _id: '5e35517cc894c90327a34baf'
    name: 'bob'
}

const insertRecords = async () => {
    await Quiz.create(record);
};

insertRecords();
```

Results in the following document:

```
{
   _id: '5e35517cc894c90327a34baf'
   name: 'bob'
}
```

As can be seen, the `_id` supplied in the query, as long as it's a valid ObjectID, would replace the `_id` that was supposed to be auto generated by mongo.

Is there a way to check if this `_id` field is in the query so that I can reject the API request? The `.create` method triggers the pre `save` middleware hook which would always have the `_id` of the final document so I cannot depend on it to know whether the `_id` was in the query or it's the auto generated one.

The only option I found is to disable the `_id` field altogether but this does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution #1 - Use `.create()` method with an explicit object.

It's actually easier than you think. This is self-explanatory - we only define what we want to allow. Mongoose will ignore anything that's not in the object.

```js
const record = {
    _id: '5e35517cc894c90327a34baf'
    name: 'bob'
}

const insertRecords = async () => {
    await Quiz.create({
      name: record.name // only allow names.
    });
};

insertRecords();
```

---

### Solution #2 - Define a function to clear unwanted objects.

You can define a helper function to clear out unwanted fields.

```js
const filterObj = (obj, ...allowedFields) => {
  const newObject = {};

  // If the current field is one of the allowed fields, keep them in the new object.
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((el) => {
    if (allowedFields.includes(el)) {
      newObject[el] = obj[el];
    }
  });

  return newObject;
};
```

How to use:

```js
const filteredRecord = filterObj(record, 'name'); // arbitrary list of allowed fields. In this case, we'll only allow 'name'.
await Quiz.create(filteredRecord);
```

Comment: very nice solutions but it's quite awkward that there is no easy way to access the original query when creating a new document. I don't know if this is mongoose or mongodb limitation

Comment: I believe it's MongoDB limitation, but the above snippet should work fine. Please mark my answer as accepted if it works for you. Thanks.

Comment: done...was going to do so just waited for more answers in case there was a native solution in mongoose but it looks like a limitation as you say...thanks :)